# Using createDocumentFragment to replace an existing column in a table

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, documentfragment

I've read that createDocumentFragment is way more faster than appending elements one by one to the DOM in a for-loop, e.g. see [here](https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g).

**What I want to do:**

1. Create a table column in a document fragment. This column should contain numbers from an array (for example "ratings").
2. After that I want to replace an existing column with the new one (the "fragment" one). So I can put the whole column to the DOM all at once.

**My problem:**

I can't really figure out how to replace an existing column if there already is one. Appending on the other hand is no problem.

My JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEqG9/2/

Helpful links, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598916/speed-efficiency-of-multiple-dom-appendchild) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652420/inserting-a-nested-div-structure-with-createdocumentfragment)

**HTML**

```
<table id = "table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A.H.Hattray </td>
        <td id = "row0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Icke_eben </td>
        <td id = "row1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John_Doe123 </td>
        <td id = "row2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var rating = [1, 10, 3];
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


for (var i = 0, len = rating.length; i < len; i++){ 
    var element = document.createElement('tr');
    element.innerHTML = rating[i];
    fragment.appendChild(element);
}
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(fragment); //I know here should be the code to replace the second column!
```

Comment: no, you can only changes rows with one chunk, not columns. you would need to append the whole table or modify the existing column in-place via the dom.

Comment: Columns can't be put into the table all at once because a column is a bunch of different cells in each of a whole bunch of rows - it's not an entity by itself.  One thing you could do for good performance is to temporarily hide the table with `display: none`, add all your rows/cells and then show the table again.  This should allow the browser to avoid intermediate layout issues every time you add a new cell and you should only get one repaint with the final content.

Comment: Can't you just replace the content of the cells, rather than the entire cell?

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks, hiding and showing the table after it has been completely loaded is a good idea! My problem was that in my table the contents (of the ratings) were showing up a little bit later than the names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code demonstrates that it is possible to manipulate an existing table in a **DocumentFragment**.

```
var rating = [1, 10, 3];
var theTable = document.getElementById('table');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
frag.appendChild(theTable);
var col2 = frag.querySelectorAll('tr td:nth-of-type(2)');
for (var i=0; i < col2.length; i++) {
    col2[i].innerHTML = rating[i];
}
// it is also possible to use insertCell and deleteCell
var theRows = frag.querySelectorAll('tr');
for (var i=0; i < theRows.length; i++) {
    var x = theRows[i].insertCell(1);
    if (i > 0) 
        x.innerHTML = 'new one';
    else
        x.innerHTML = 'The Header';
}
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

(Making the new cell in the first row a TH element, rather than TD requires a little more work, using `createElement` and `appendChild` or `insertBefore`.)

If you step through this the table is removed from the DOM when appended to the fragment, then reappears when the fragment is appended to the body.

Comment: Ah, great, thank you. I've tried it in jsfiddle and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/LEqG9/7/ and http://jsfiddle.net/LEqG9/6/ (without a new column).

Answer (score 2):

Columns can't be put into the table all at once (and thus won't work as a fragment) because a column is a bunch of different cells in each of a whole bunch of rows - it's not an entity by itself.

One thing you could do for good performance is to temporarily hide the table with `display: none`, add all your rows/cells and then show the table again. This should allow the browser to avoid intermediate layout issues every time you add a new cell and you should only get one repaint with the final content.

Comment: thanks, "display:none" in the CSS and showing the table again with  jQuery worked. $('table').show(); [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LEqG9/3/)